# Vue.js and Firestore replace array on db change

Tags: javascript, firebase, vuejs2, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Vue.js and Firestore. I have some buttons that are dynamic.

When I edit a button and push the changes to the db it adds to my array instead of replacing it.

If I refresh the page everything works correctly.

I am assuming there is a way to make the array reactive

here is my code:

```
<template>
  <v-app id="app">
    <Navbar />
    <router-view :key="$route.fullPath"></router-view>
    <v-speed-dial
      v-model="fab"
      fixed
      bottom
      right
      direction="top"
      transition="scale-transition"
    >
      <v-btn
        slot="activator"
        v-model="fab"
        color="blue-grey darken-2"
        dark
        fab
      >
        <v-icon>directions_run</v-icon>
        <v-icon>close</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
      <span v-for="tag in tags" :key="tag.icon">
        <v-btn
        fab
        dark
        small
        :color="tag.color"
        >
          <v-icon>{{tag.icon}}</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </span> 
    </v-speed-dial>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import Navbar from '@/components/layout/Navbar'
import db from '@/firebase/init'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  data() {
    return {
      fab: false,
      tags: []
    }
  },
  components: {
    Navbar: Navbar
  },
  created() {
    let tagRef = db.collection('tags').orderBy('order')
    tagRef.onSnapshot(snapshot => {
        snapshot.docChanges().forEach(snap => {
          let tag = snap.doc
          this.tags.push(tag.data())
        })
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: you can see changes https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots and add only them, or you can clear array before adding data.

Comment: Would you mind showing me how?

Comment: Try: this.tags.length  = 0 inside your onSnapshot. before pushing any items.

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work. That causes the code to only add one to the array

Comment: Yes, sorry i haven't seen that u use docChanges.  It have to work without it. But try this before : snap.data() instead of  let tag = snap.doc ... tag.data()

Comment: based on your comment I think you wanted me to try this: `this.tags.push(snap.doc.data())` and comment out `let tag = snap.doc` but that did not work either

Comment: That is what I thought you asked but this is what happens `TypeError: snap.data is not a function`

Comment: This is why i hate js, nor editor never tell you what properties or functions object has. So i made research. And your code works fine. But before add new tag you have to find and remove old tag in your array. Or do as i said before - clear you array  and don't use docChanges.

Comment: I moved the code out of App.vue and it is working. I am not sure why that mattered though.

Comment: put something in an answer and I will except it. I appreciate you helping

Comment: ok, but make sure it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two ways. First: find and replace your outdated tag. Or clear array and re-add all items with new one.

Second way may looks like:

```
 created() {
 let self = this// you can't use "this" inside onSnapshot
    let tagRef = db.collection('tags').orderBy('order')
    tagRef.onSnapshot(snapshot => {
     self.tags.length = 0
          snapshot.forEach(snap => {
          self.tags.push(tag.data())
        })
    })
  }
```